# Android OAUTH Without Any Special Library

Tags: android, oauth, yelp

Quick background.  I am not a computer scientist or programmer.  Just trying to learn Android as a personal challenge (helps me stay in touch with the modern world, so I can understand my kids better).  I started out very simple, and am slowly trying to tackle more challenging skills.

Right now, I am struggling to get OAUTH authentication working to connect to the Yelp API.  I have read a bunch of blog posts.  I have searched and read a bunch of topics here.  Some are helpful, some are too advanced for me.

I understand that there are libraries that can be used for OAUTH.  For example, I can install the signpost library and use that.  That may be my next step.  Right now, I have been trying to connect to the YELP API without using any special library (remember, this is a learning exercise for me).

The YELP documentation seems simple enough.

[Screenshot of YELP API documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/leuMw.png)

I have my Client ID, and Client Secret.  I tried to request an access token using the following lines of code.

[Lines of code used to request access token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/768Wx.png)

My attempt fails miserably.  I get Error response code: 400.

Can you help point out my error?

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: 400 means a bad response from the server ! ... Looking at your code more, maybe it's supposed to be handled by Https instead of Http ... But I'm only a noob to android dev

Answer (score 0):

`setRequestProperty(String key, String value)` method is for neither query parameters nor form parameters. The method is for setting HTTP headers to send.

**To set your client ID and client secret:**

```java
String credentials = String.format("%s:%s", "MyClientId", "MyClientSecret");
byte[] credentialsBytes = credentials.getBytes("UTF-8");
String encoded = org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64String(credentialsBytes);
String authorization = String.format("Basic %s", encoded);

hURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", authorization);
```

**To embed request parameters in the request body:**

```java
hURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
byte[] bytes = "grant_type=client_credentials".getBytes("UTF-8");
OutputStream out = hURLConnection.getOutputStream();
out.write(bytes);
out.flush();
```

If Yelp API supports *"RFC 6750, [2.2. Form-Encoded Body Parameter](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750#section-2.2)"*, your client ID and client secret can be embedded in the request body together with the `grant_type` request parameter.

```java
byte[] bytes = "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=MyClientId&client_secret=MyClientSecret".getBytes("UTF-8");
```

Comment: Thanks.  That helped me.  Sending the  grant type, client id, and client secret in the body of the request did it.